# Ant : Getting List of directories present in SVN using Ant

Tags: svn, ant

I have a problem in getting the list of directories from the svn in ant. I want to get the list of directories  like

**dirset id="dir.contents" dir="E:\" includes="*"

property name="ver.dir.contents" refid="dir.contents"

for list="${ver.dir.contents}" delimiter=";" param="versions"**

This results in folders that are present in my E drive with separator as ";". Likewise i want to get the list of directories in my svn url. I tried List task in svn, but in vain. I used this ant

**svn svnkit="true" javahl="false" username="xxxx" password="yyyyy"

list overwrite="true" property="listfiles" url="SVN URL"**

Please help me out.

Comment: Saw something here very specific to using svnkit ant tasks : http://svnkit.com/kb/user-guide-ant.html. I think you can pass " <arg value="ls"/> " for your task. And what is the error you got?.

Comment: I got error stating E:\Workspaces\Hibernate\ANT\src\com\exterro\ant\sample.xml:13: svn doesn't support the nested "list" element.